# Menu methods placement best practice

Tags: java, android

Tried to get the answer from android dev site and docs but no luck.

Just wondered on best practice as to where to store the methods that run from user selecting an option from my toolbar, currently I have all the onselection cases running in mainactivity, but as I plan on keeping the toolbar options the same for every activity I question whether mainactivity is the best place to store the methods.

Any thoughts or suggestions from experience?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a base activity and put there all the common methods. Then, the other activities (MainActivity and the rest) would extend the base activity.

For example, this could be the base activity:

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    // common methods...
}
```

And this could be your MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

This way, all the common methods are kept on a single class.

Comment: That makes alot more sense than some of the other suggestions I have heard, will do that as I much prefer to edit once in one place. Nice one thanks bud

Comment: Just had a thought, I still want to use the support library so would having the following allow this to happen: public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity and then MainActivity extends BaseActivity, from memory this would create a super > sub relationship right?

Comment: Absolutely. There's no problem at all.